# Scrollbar not working

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Below is my html file,

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 my1" id="qwer1" role="navigation">        <!--Change is made here-->
          <div class="menuBar">
            <ul class="menuList" id="menuList">
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update 1</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chat 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->
```

Below is the css file,

```
.my1
{
    position:fixed;
    left:78%;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    width:20%;
    top:14%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:scroll;
    scroll-face-color:red;
}
```

The content of the html file is well out of the sreen, but eventhough the scrollbar is not operable. Moreover, I have specified the color of the scrollbar as red but the color effect also doesnt seem to be working. Below is the screenshot of browser,

[image]

How can I activte this scrollbar?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you specified:

```
height:auto;
```

under the `.my1` rule, so the `div` will expand in height as much as needed to accommodate the content.

If you had fixed the height, you would activate the scroll bar.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/myPZB/

As far as trying to style the color of the scroll bar, the property of interest is:

```
scrollbar-face-color
```

and I think this is only supported on IE browsers at this time.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks marc, the scroll bar worked when I specified the height as 500px, but still I couldnt get the color 'red'. Any pointers on that?

Answer (score 3):

```
height:50%
```

try this..I tested ok..if 'auto' , scroll is not work

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be solved if the following meta tags are in your html:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also, be sure to remove `height auto`