# Scrollbar doesn't work. Even with height defined

Tags: html, css

I'm making a empresarial-type UI web page, and like title say, scrollbar doesn't work.

CSS of the content div:

```
#content
{
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0, 0.36, 1);

    position: fixed;
    top: 8vw;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 600vw;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Todo en Punto de Venta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/logo.png">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top_bar">
        <img src="./img/logo.png" title="logo">

        <p id="pa" oncontextmenu="return false;">Home</p>
        <p id="pb" oncontextmenu="return false;">Address</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="home">
            <p id="p0">Lorem</p>
            <p id="p1">Ipsum dolum</p>
            <p id="p2">Amet</p>
            <img src="./img/stock1.jpg" title="home">
        </div>
        <div id="about">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolum amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have defined height as [this question says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875779/scrollbar-not-working) and adding `display: flex;` but it didn't work.

Comment: You have the height set to `600vw`. You would have to have more than 600vw worth of content in your div to make it scroll.

Comment: `600vw`  is 6 times the viewport width. **MDN** The second box has a width set in vw (viewport width) units. This value is relative to the viewport width, and so 10vw is 10 percent of the width of the viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units . It should work.  @abney317

Comment: `position:fixed`does -- not -- scroll.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @deEr. `position: relative` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have the height set to 600vw. You would have to have  600vh